# No UV coordinates Substance Painter

Tags: texturing, uv, export, .fbx, texture-coordinates

Help me with my problem. I cannot solve it myself therefore I am asking you for help. When I made my model, I made the UV after all this I decided to make textures in substance painter, but this message appears in the console.

[image: substance painter error]

Comment: Perhaps you could add how (in what format) you exported the model to substance painter?

Comment: Model in fbx and uv format in png

Comment: UVs aren't picture files. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/uv_image/uv/overview.html

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem.

So i had done the mesh in Blender, and UV unwrapped it as well. Export, and same error in Substance Painter.

Solution was to while you export in Blender, be sure to check the *Selected Object*, and prior to choosing *File > Export*, be sure to either select all objects in the scene you want exported in the OBJ/FBX file, or delete everything else in the scene.

As I understand it, when you export the FBX or OBJ in Blender, it takes every single item in the scene (meshes, hidden meshes, cameras, stuff like that), and while you have the mesh you wanted to put in Substance Painter, you have all the other objects there as well.

In my case, I had some duplicates on separate layer for "backups", which came with the FBX into Substance Painter, even though I chose the mesh in Blender 3D viewport, I didn't have the *Selected Objects* checked in export properties.

Comment: Thank you for this answer!!! I spent hours trying to figure it.

Answer (score 0):

this post is old but I recently encountered the problem. If you still have the error in Painter after making sure you have only one object exported, try to apply any modifier you have going on on the object before exporting. In my case, a Collision modifier I used for a cloth simulation was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Maya, I selected everything I wanted to export and combined the polys then exported it in FBX format. It didn't destroy the UV.

I am not sure if it works well in obj. format, had issues with that.

If it says *polySurface6* (or whatever name you gave the poly) has no UV coordinate. Go back to Maya or whatever software you imported it from and ungroup it, freeze transformation reassign-unfold the UV and delete its history.

If all this didn't work, combining the polys and exporting in FBX format will work for sure.